# UglifyJS using NPM in Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, uglifyjs

I am on a Windows 7 box, and I recently installed the most recent version of Node from NodeJS.org

I then ran...

```
C:\Users\jcreamer>npm install -g uglify-js  
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js  
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js  
C:\Users\jcreamer\AppData\Roaming\npm\uglifyjs -> C:\Users\jcreamer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js\bin\uglifyjs   
uglify-js@1.2.3 C:\Users\jcreamer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglify-js
```

And restarted command prompt, but I still cannot run...

```
cd c:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\  
node uglifyjs -o app.min.js app.js
```

I get this error...

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick  
              ^  
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\analytics\uglifyjs'  
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)  
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)  
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)  
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Is there something else I need to do?

**UPDATE**
Even after I ran the npm as administartor, if I run

```
C:\Users\jcreamer>uglifyjs
```

I get...

```
C:\Users\jcreamer>"C:\Users\jcreamer\AppData\Roaming\npm\\.\node_modules\uglify-js\bin\uglifyjs"
'"C:\Users\jcreamer\AppData\Roaming\npm\\.\node_modules\uglify-js\bin\uglifyjs"' is not recognized as an internal or external comm
and,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Global installs are for command-line utilities.

As you can see the `uglifyjs` command line utility is dropped into your path, at `C:\Users\jcreamer\AppData\Roaming\npm\uglifyjs` (which is a link to uglify's `bin\uglifyjs` as you can see in the output.)

@alessioalex You no longer need admin packages to install a global package.  The node MSI installer sets the global default prefix to `%APPDATA%\npm`, so users have the ability to write to it.

If you're trying to `require("uglify-js")` in your node program, then you should install it locally, not with the -g.  It looks like you're trying to use it as a standalone util, so alessioalex's #2 suggestion is exactly right.  Just type `uglifyjs` to use it, not `node uglifyjs`.

Comment: Running just uglifyjs is giving me the '"C:\Users\jcreamer\AppData\Roaming\npm\\.\node_modules\uglify-js\bin\uglifyjs"' is not recognized as an internal or external comm
and,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sure! Before I do that, I want to make sure I am 100% sure I am doing it correctly... So, I should...
1. Run npm -g install uglify-js
2. Run uglifyjs -o app.min.js app.js
And that should work?

Comment: You're doing things ok, the same happens to me.

Answer (score 12):

If you have Windows, Then use the following command

```
npm -g install uglify-js
```

the `-g` flag indicates that this is a global installation and will set the env path.

Working for me. Let me know if it is working for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. Run the command prompt with administrator privileges when installing a global package like this one (right click -> Run as administrator).
2. Instead of `node uglifyjs...` use `uglifyjs` directly. Since it's installed globally you don't need to call it with node in front, that makes no sense.

Comment: Tried that, check out my update to the question to see what happened... thanks for your help on this!